# Unknown compiler warnings

Tags: visual-studio, qt, compiler-warnings

I was playing around with QWT on MSVS2017 and saw a list of non-MSVC warnings disabled in the compiler options, eg: -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458.
Where are these options defined?  I've looked in the Qt docs but don't find them.  Are they possibly Clang warnings being disabled?

-Max

Comment: It's a combination of warning level and number to output the warning at a specific level. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=vs-2017

Comment: Of course, but microsoft uses 4 digit numbers, not 5.

Comment: Right, the warning numbers are of 4 digits. But as i wrote above the warning options you mention in the question are combinations of level and warning number. First digit is the level the warning should be reported at and the tailing 4 digits are the warning number. Example: `-w34100` means that warning `4100` should be treated as level 3 warning. If you take a look at the linked document of my previous comment it should be clear.

Comment: OK, I understand now.  It is just changing the level of those warnings. THanks.  You should make this the answer rather than a comment.